# Remoção árvore binária

Tags: c, grafo, árvore-binária

Pessoal como fica a árvore após a remocão do número 40?

No meu entendimento, no lugar do 40 seria o número 41, direita 44 e esquerda 30. E a direita do 44 o número 49, to certo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Bom, você tem que definir qual metodologia adotar. Você pode escolher o nó a esquerda, `30`, como o novo nó que ficará no lugar do `40` e então neste caso você terá que buscar o nó mais a direita do nó `30`, para alocar o nó que estava a direita do `40`, o `44`. Ou você também pode escolher o `44` como o nó que ficará no lugar do `40`, e neste caso você terá que procurar o nó mais a esquerda do `44` para alocar o que estava a esquerda do `40`, no caso o `30`. De qualquer forma isso depende da sua metodologia, e desta forma não irá desbalancear a sua árvore. Não seria viável você tentar reorganiza-la de modo a colocar o `41` no lugar do nó removido, isso porque seria trabalhoso demais garantir que a árvore não seria desbalanceada.

[image: Slide - Professor Marcos Caetano - UnB]
Slide do professor Marcos Caetano - UnB.

Como poder ver, a sua árvore continuará balanceada
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Então baseado no que ele pediu no enunciado: "Para que se continue tendo a configuração de uma árvore binária de busca, após a remoção dos nós mostrados, abaixo, qual será a nova configuração das árvores? Redesenhe." Eu poderia colocar no lugar do 40, o número 41 igual eu fiz? Ele poderia considerar?

Comment: Não poderia, você tem que considerar que não sabe quais os valores de cada nó, até porque ela não segue uma ordem numérica, e você somente sabe que menor fica à esquerda e maior à direita. Então, você somente pode definir qual nó filho ficará no lugar, se o da esquerda ou da direita. A árvore continuará sendo uma árvore binária de busca em qualquer uma das duas opções.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que posso perceber esta árvore trata-se de uma árvore binária de busca (ABB).

Sempre que um nó for removido, o que substituirá sua posição na árvore deve manter a árvore como sendo ainda uma árvore binária de busca. Ou seja, números menores à esquerda e números maiores à direita. Para isso deve-se pegar o filho da subárvore à esquerda que está mais à direita e colocar no lugar do nó que será removido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso, como não há subárvore à esquerda, mas sim apenas um nó, é esse nó à esquerda que irá ser colocado no lugar. Ou seja, o 30 substituirá a posição do 40 na ABB.

Isso ocorre assim pelo fato de que o maior elemento na subárvore à esquerda é maior que o menor elemento da subárvore à direita.

Você pode entender mais sobre remoção em Árvore Binária de Busca nesse [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0Yu9BSYXGY). Foi da lá que tirei essa imagem.

Comment: Então, mas tenho uma dúvida, ele pedi isso no exercício, na prova: "Para que se continue tendo a configuração de uma árvore binária de busca, após a remoção dos nós mostrados, abaixo, qual será a nova configuração das árvores? Redesenhe."

Answer (score 0):

Apenas remova o desejado e pegue ou maior à esquerda ou o menor à direita e ponha em seu lugar.